# Эмуляция джойстика в linux

Tags: linux

Имеется: arduino uno с двумя джойстиками (нативные ардуиновские), которая шлёт данные по usb/serial на мой компьютер с linux, программа, которая читает данные. Эта программа должна эмулировать джойстик. Данные успешно читаются, но как эмуировать джойстик - непонятно.

Какие существуют для этих целей библиотеки/утилиты в linux?

Comment: @val ищите как создавать HID устройства в Linux. [Например](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116709/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/52187/4827341

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем использовать *USB/serial*? Почему не взять https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary и превратить ваш *Arduino* в полноценное `USB HID` устройство? В этом случае вам не понадобятся никакие дополнительные программы на вашем linux PC.

Если вы все-таки хотите заниматься <s>извращениями</s> эмуляцией - проще всего это сделать с помощью [`libsuinput`](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/libsuinput)